# Remove first lines within cells in libreoffice calc

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, calc

I have a large no of cells in libreoffice calc, and every cell have two lines. I want to remove every first line from each cell. Any easy method?
This piece of code works perfect in VBA excel but dont run in libreoffice calc.

{
Sub RemoveFirstLine(ByRef Target As Range)

```
Dim xCell As Range

For Each xCell In Target.Cells

    xCell.Value = Right(xCell.Value, Len(xCell.Value) - InStr(1, xCell.Value, vbLf))

Next
```

End Sub

Sub StartRemove()

Dim xRng As Range

On Error Resume Next

Set xRng = Application.InputBox("Please select range:", "Excel 10 Tutorial", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)

If xRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

On Error Resume Next

RemoveFirstLine xRng

End Sub
}

[image]

Comment: Where do you want the result? In a new column? Or do you want a macro that makes the edits in-place? What have you tried so far? How much experience do you have with formulas? How much experience do you have with macro programming? ... So many unanswered questions...

Comment: I want the result in the same columns. I dont know about macros, I just have huge no of cells in a column and I cant edit every cell to remove first line manually. I have tried nothing rather than doing manually. Never used formulas though. Little hands on regex. No idea about macro programming too

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a macro for this task, use [Find&Replace](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.4/en-US/text/shared/01/02100000.html?System=WIN&DbPAR=CALC&HID=.uno:SearchDialog#bm_id7754440).

Press **Ctrl+H** or choose Edit-Find&Replace

Input to field Find **.*\n**, set Other Options - Regular expressions to ON, click Replace All

[Remove first lines.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbvI8.png)